# Best method for storing tabulated user data cordova app for cross-device sync

Tags: android, ios, mysql, cordova

So I have an app that I want to build, and it needs a sync feature. The basic premise of the app is that the user will be able to store some tabulated data in it. I then want to be able to upload and store that data to a server so they can sync it across devices.

As the question states, it needs to be cross-platform, specifically Cordova. I was thinking about using a MySQL database with tables for each user's data. Then use calls on that user-specific table to sync and retrieve data. Are there any drawbacks to that approach? Better ways of handling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) (server) and [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) (client). Syncing is made quite easy in these databases.

> PouchDB is an open-source JavaScript database inspired by Apache CouchDB that is designed to run well within the browser.
>
> PouchDB was created to help web developers build applications that work as well offline as they do online.
>
> It enables applications to store data locally while offline, then synchronize it with CouchDB and compatible servers when the application is back online, keeping the user's data in sync no matter where they next login.

It is:

- *Cross Browser*: Works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE and Node.js
- *Lightweight*: PouchDB is just a script tag and 46KB (gzipped)
- *Easy to Learn*: Requires some programming knowledge, however PouchDB is a piece of cake to learn.
- *Open Source*: Everything is developed out in the open on Github, contributors always welcome!

See this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758964/architecture-of-an-app-when-using-couchdb-pouchdb) to get more in-depth of the architecture of using PouchDB/CouchDB.